# I transfer bitcoin to someone i don't know ,

Tags: revert-transaction

i make a mistake  and transfer my bitcoin to someone I really don't know who is how could i get back the money ?
لقد قمت في ارسال المال لمحفظه  شخص  انا لا اعرفه كيف لي ان استرد المال ؟

Answer (score 5):

> **how could i get back the money?**

You can't.

Bitcoin transactions cannot be reversed, cancelled or undone.

> **[I transferred] my bitcoin to someone I really don't know**

If you have contact details for the person, you can ask them if they are willing to create a new transaction to send some money back to you.

If you only know a Bitcoin address, you cannot get contact details from that address. A bitcoin address does not identify a person, a place or a business. It is just a number, effectively a random number.

Comment: so I cant get the bitcoin back at all ?

Comment: I'm not  sure how I could make it any clearer.